# Relating Polygons to Results in AngularJS & Leaflet

Tags: javascript, polygon, leaflet, leaflet-draw, angularjs

I am using `Lealfet.draw` tools for creating polygons and then fetching results from a database  based on the coordinates of those polygons. I want to be able to relate each polygon to it's corresponding result. **Ideally if a user hovers over the result, the corresponding polygon should get highlighted**. is there a leaflet functionality for doing such thing or any other alternative?

**Map creation**

```
 leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {

            leafletData.getLayers().then(function(baselayers) {
                var drawnItems = baselayers.overlays.draw;

                map.on('draw:created', function(e) {

                    var layer = e.layer;


                    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);



                    console.log(JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON()));
                    coordinates_selected = layer.toGeoJSON();

                });
            });
        });
```

**fetching results and displaying it**

```
function map(obj) {

            var o = obj.data.hits.hits;
            var b = [];
            for (var i in o) {
                o[i]._source.id = o[i]._source.compendium_id;
                try {
                    b.push(o[i]._source.metadata.o2r.spatial.union.features[0]);

                    {


                    }
                    throw error()
                } catch (g) {
                    console.error("missing spatial");
                }
            }
            $log.debug('mconfiging result: %o', o, b);
            angular.extend($scope, {
                geojson: {
                    data: b,
                    style: {
                        fillColor: "green",
                        weight: 2,
                        opacity: 1,
                        color: 'white',
                        dashArray: '3',
                        fillOpacity: 0.7
                    }
                }
            });


            return obj;
        }
```